# How to get a trace listener filter information level?

Tags: c#, .net, trace

I tries to get listeners to work with "filters". In the C# i uses...

```
Trace.TraceWarning(EntryText);
Trace.TraceInformation(EntryText);
Trace.TraceError(EntryText);
```

In the app.config file i have written...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup>
  <system.diagnostics>    
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\DBLog\application.log" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>       
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

I don't understand how to apply the swithes element in app.config file to get the desired level of information. For example just show all the TraceError in an production and all logging in a test...

Answer (score 1):

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add name="myListener" 
        type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\DBLog\application.log" >
        <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Error" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4"/>
  </system.diagnostics>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thx, But when i put filters tag inside my listeners i tells me that is a invalide tag and when debuging the program i Unrecognized element 'filter'.